# How can I get rep on Meta?

Tags: support

I wanted to vote up a question on meta that I estimated relevant but have only 1 rep.
How can I get rep on meta? By asking questions? (my understanding is that mods answer here)
Do people transfer their rep from other sites? 
[This login is shared with stackoverflow and serverfault, where I have enough points to vote (not much, I participate since a few days ago).]

Comment: Just hang around and write... *anything*. It takes serious skill to *not* get rep on meta...

Comment: +1 from me, here you go, have 10 rep, you can upvote now =)

Comment: @Shog9 You mean like being me? :)

Comment: For irony purposes, we're now required to serially downvote @Shog9 's posts

Comment: Apparently asking for it works pretty well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Participate.**

Once you have 200 Reputation on any of the other sites your on, you can re-associate your account in the accounts tab on your user profile for a boost of 100 Rep here, however, not just moderators posts here. Anyone that has the answer to the question, or has an opinion is welcome to participate.

The only requirement is you having an account on one of the [Trilogy Sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157006/what-is-the-stack-overflow-trilogy)

Answer (score 3):

Like the other sites, it helps if you write well-reasoned answers in clear English, at least for non-joke posts.

Unlike the other sites, it helps if you write stuff that's in tune with how the community feels, since voting here represents "I like/dislike this."  So, purely from the standpoint of getting rep, you'll benefit from posting feature requests that other people will support, and withholding the ones that other people won't like.  See [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You get rep on meta the same way you would on other sites; answering questions, asking questions, getting up-voted.

I'm not aware of a way to transfer rep from one site to another.

Comment: You can't transfer but you can get the rep bonus if you have >200 rep on any of the associated sites.

Comment: @Diago - this is true.