# What is the Stack Overflow "trilogy"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

What are people referring to when they talk about [the Stack Overflow "trilogy"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/what-is-the-correct-name-to-use-when-referencing-the-trilogy-sites/50931#50931)? Sometimes they refer to it as the Stack Exchange trilogy...

Comment: This was closed, but I think it is more useful than having to scroll down to the bottom of the glossary page to get the answer one is looking for... especially in, for example, [Google search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+trilogy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this question myself:

As detailed on [the official blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/), the Stack Overflow trilogy includes the first three projects:

1. [**StackOverflow.com**](http://stackoverflow.com) for programmers
2. [**ServerFault.com**](http://serverfault.com) for sys admins and support specialists
3. [**SuperUser.com**](http://superuser.com) for computer enthusiasts and power usrs

Their successes spawned the implementation of the [StackExchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) network with the multitude of Q&A websites you see today.

Comment: Trilogy is also mentioned in the [Stack Exchange Glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks - good suggestion.

Comment: Better to say the success of SO spawned the network. ServerFault is about 1.5% of the size and 1% of the activity of SO. Most of that is just spillover from SO.